Querying layer in QGIS Model Designer
How can I create a query in a layer using the Model Designer in QGIS, like the example shown in the picture below?
How i can make this in Model Designer?


Use the "Execute SQL" algorithm. Select the inputs, they are called input1, input2, ..., based on the order they are selected under the "three dots symbol" to the right.

